Unity : UI Pause Menu Prefab
I've been having this strange issue that when I make my UI a Prefab it breaks all the buttons so I can't press any of them, I followed the Brackeys tutorial to make this pause menu, but it works when its only in one scene in the project where I first put it in even as a prefab, all other copies are broken. Is there a reason this would happen?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;


public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject PauseUI;
    public GameObject OptionsUI;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PauseUI.SetActive(false);
        OptionsUI.SetActive(false);

        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else {
                Pause();
            }
        }

        
        
    }

    public void Resume() {
        PauseUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    private void Pause () {
        PauseUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    public void QUITOnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void Options()
    {
        PauseUI.SetActive(false);
        OptionsUI.SetActive(true);

    }
    public void Back()
    {
        PauseUI.SetActive(true);
        OptionsUI.SetActive(false);

    }


    public void SetVolume(float volume)
    {

        audioMixer.SetFloat("volume", volume);
    }


}


I tried re-adding the EventManager, I've tried re-linking the code, but nothing seems to fix this problem.

Is there an EventSystem in all scenes?

Yes there is an EventSystem in all scenes

Do the buttons not interact at all (not even hover) or is it just methods not being called?

When you make a prefab, serialized references (the drag and drop references in inspectors) all break UNLESS they are all to objects in the exact same hierarchy as the prefab. So basically the prefab can only store references to components on itself and its children objects.
I’m guessing here, but I suspect in your scene, your buttons are referencing UI that is not contained in its own hierarchy. So when you make it a prefab, these references are broken. If this is the case you’d see some NullReferenceExceptions in the console when you run the scene and click a button.
You either need to manually drag all those references again when you put the prefabs into the scene, or you need to rethink your hierarchy so that the references can stay internal to the prefab’s hierarchy.
If this is not the case you need to edit your question to provide more context so we can help you better.
